# Parsing of newest unanswered C++ questions seems to have broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, unanswered-questions

I have a bookmark to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=newest, which has always shown me the newest unanswered questions for C++ (%2b being "+", URL-encoded).

This URL now shows me C questions rather than C++ questions (and the search box shows [c]).

If I then click on the C++ button I get taken to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%20c%2b%2b, which still shows only C questions, and now the search box shows [c] [c].

tagged/c%2b%2b still works elsewhere on the site, but under unanswered it doesn't.

Comment: If you click it a third time you get [c] [c] [c]. Maybe it's incrementing the number of `c`s when you click `c++`.

Comment: @juergen I said in the question that it works elsewhere. That doesn't alter the fact that it doesn't work under unanswered/tagged. What do you mean unanswered works too?

Comment: You're right. Clicking on unanswered and then C++ does not work. I did it the other way around.

Comment: I concur with this, and note it is still lunked in the head as of todays date.

Comment: Now is 21 Dec 2012 and this bug is still exists. Do StackOverflow's authors look at 'meta' part of their site ?

Comment: This is still broken. But there is a workaround: `http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/cpp?tab=newest` - because cpp is a synonym for the c++ tag. Doesn't necessarily help with all the other tags with "+" in them though.

Comment: @Asad ha it's funny because c++ in C increments the variable c! /sarcasm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed.