# Correctly filtering for 'C++' among 'visual-studio-2010' unanswered questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing of newest unanswered C++ questions seems to have broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157367/parsing-of-newest-unanswered-c-questions-seems-to-have-broken)

Am I using StackExchange incorrectly?  I start by looking at all unanswered questions at this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

There, I filter for "visual-studio-2010" questions by clicking on the gray chicklet in the right-hand column. I end up at this URL, and that seems fine: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/visual-studio-2010  AT this point, I can see "3,901 questions with no answers tagged with visual-studio-2010".

I further want to filter to questions involving visual studio and C++, so I click the "c++" chicklet in the right-hand column. That takes me to this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/visual-studio-2010%20c%2b%2b

But the thing is I'm looking at "questions with no answers tagged with 'visual-studio-2010' 'c'". Note that's 'c', and not 'c++'.

Am I don't something incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like a bug. It's not quite the same, but you can use [this view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20visual-studio-2010?sort=unanswered) instead for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

Does seem to be a bug, yes.
Until it is fixed, you can get to see the questions you want by typing
`[c++] [visual-studio-2010] answers:0`
in the search box.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is , filter for  `visual-studio-2010`  then, further filter for `c++`, then at the bottom on favorite tags input you enter `c` and then you will see `c` questions highlighted like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/visual-studio-2010%20c++).

Comment: is it possible to explain the down-vote ?